# Удаление элемента из vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

Необходимо удалить i-Й элемент вектора, если выполнится условие, пытаюсь и не получается. Помогите пожалуйста;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugO2w.png

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        if (buls[i].pos.x < buls[i].targetPos.x) buls[i].pos.x += 1;
        if (buls[i].pos.y < buls[i].targetPos.y) buls[i].pos.y += 1;
        if (buls[i].pos.x > buls[i].targetPos.x) buls[i].pos.x -= 1;
        if (buls[i].pos.y > buls[i].targetPos.y) buls[i].pos.y -= 1;
        if (buls[i].pos == buls[i].targetPos) {
            buls.erase(i); // здесь ошибка
        }
        buls[i].sprite.setPosition(buls[i].pos);
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Смущает, например, конкретное 99 в цикле. Как именно объявлен `bulls`. Да и все ваши `if`'ы тоже выглядят немного излишними, если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите. Приведите-та вашу задачу полностью, что вы хотите, и соответственно типы и объявления переменных. А то, боюсь, мы будем рассказывать, какой рукой держать микроскоп, а не чем и как забить гвоздь. Да, по сути вопроса - удалять надо через итератор... Только вот при этом и количество элементов изменится, да и посмотрите - если вы удалите, то к какому элементу вектора будет применено `.sprite.setPosition()`?

Answer (score 0):

Предложу вам свой способ удаления элемента из массива vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buls.size(); i++) {
    if (buls[i].pos == buls[i].targetPos) {
        for (int j = i; j < buls.size()-1; j++) {
            buls[j] = buls[j + 1];
        }
        i--; // необходимо, чтобы обработка остальной части массива продолжилось корректно
        buls.pop_back();
    }
}
```